# I get undefined values in my field value when inserting multiple documents after converting csv to json string and parsing. Why?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, csv

Basically, I am trying to do an import function for csv files where the csv file will get converted to json before then being inserted into the mongodb. This is my code.

```
//require the csvtojson converter class 
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
// create a new converter object
var converter = new Converter({});
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// call the fromFile function which takes in the path to your 
// csv file as well as a callback function
converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-
New_2017.csv",function(err,result){
// if an error has occured then handle it
if(err){
    console.log("An Error Has Occured");
    console.log(err);  
} 
// the result of the conversion
var jsonResult  = result;
console.log(jsonResult);
var jsobject= JSON.stringify(jsonResult);
var jsonobject= JSON.parse(jsobject);
var f = jsonobject.length;
console.log(f);
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < f; i++){
    var insertDocument = function() {
    db.collection('documents').insertOne({
//'_id': Object.keys(obj).length,
        'indexNo' : jsonobject.indexNo,
        'samID': jsonobject.samID,
        'Type': jsonobject.Type,
        'InventoryStatus': jsonobject.InventoryStatus,
        'dateIn':jsonobject.dateIn,
        'Remarks':jsonobject.Remarks,
        'dateOut':jsonobject.dateOut,
        //'Remarks':jsonobject.remarks,
        'ntaSamRequestRef': jsonobject.ntaSamReqRef
        //'Created Date': "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>"
    }, function(err, results) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(results);

    });
    };
        insertDocument(db, function() {
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else{
                console.log('insert');
            }
            db.close();
        });
        }   
 });
        console.log("Inserted " + f + " document into the documents 
        collection.");
 });
```

So far, I have tried doing this of converting a random file with 1400 records into a json string before parsing and then inserting it. But somehow I keep getting undefined from my fields whenever I insert, the result show my respective field with undefined values.

**Which part of my `jsonobject.indexNo` is wrong in the sense that is `jsonobject.field1value` and `jsonobject.field2value` etc. How should I get the values from my json string then after parsing?**

I am using node.js to run it and mongodb as database. I can convert nicely just this part about inserting the documents inside. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you stringifying the original result and then parsing it again? The original result will be a json object. When you debug, are you getting the expected fields in the result object?

Comment: @RedJandal I wanted to ensure it is a string first before parsing it

Comment: These lines `var jsobject= JSON.stringify(jsonResult); var jsonobject= JSON.parse(jsobject);` should be completely unnecessary since the data is "already" a JavaScript Object. This is "not" JSON. So you should not be thinking of it as such. The main problem here is lack of proper iterator control for respecting callbacks to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.collection('documents').insertOne is an async method , you can't run it in a loop like that. Workaround is you can use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) to handle it. Suggest to use [async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Eg:

```
 // Consider jsonResult is an array
 var jsonResult  = result;

 async.each(jsonResult,
   // Here, jsonobject is a child object of jsonResult array
   function(jsonobject, callback){
     db.collection('documents').insertOne({
      //'_id': Object.keys(obj).length,
      'indexNo' : jsonobject.indexNo,
      'samID': jsonobject.samID,
      'Type': jsonobject.Type,
      'InventoryStatus': jsonobject.InventoryStatus,
      'dateIn':jsonobject.dateIn,
      'Remarks':jsonobject.Remarks,
      'dateOut':jsonobject.dateOut,
      //'Remarks':jsonobject.remarks,
      'ntaSamRequestRef': jsonobject.ntaSamReqRef
      //'Created Date': "<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>"
     });

     // Async call is done, trigger callback
     callback();
 },
 // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
 function(err){
   // All tasks are done now
   doSomethingOnceAllAreDone();
 }
);
```

Comment: Does that mean I should put items in an array before using `async.each` and is the way I call these field values wrong ?

Comment: Probably should be "at least" `async.eachLimit` otherwise there are a lot of concurrent calls on the stack.

Comment: jsonResult is an array right? You can use it as long it is an array. Just replace it with items from my code . Probably can use async.eachLimit to prevent concurrent calls like @Neil Lunn said.

Comment: @digit Sorry for the late reply. Is `f`important ? What is `item` for and what should I replace it with?